# I cannot install the last version of spatstat.utils

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install the latest version of spatstat.utils, which is 3.0.1. However, I don't know why I get the version 2.3.0.
I attach an screenshot with the error message

[image]

Is there any way of telling R that the latest version should be installed?

Comment: There is no error message. The message says that installation succeeded. But also: please don't post screenshots of text in the future. Read up [how to format your questions properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and post the formatted code/text.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I checked out the description folder of spatstat.utils and it says that it is version 2.3.0. D you kno why I don'y get the latest version?

Comment: Ah that's true. Well the message you posted explains that too (though admittedly not straightforwardly): to get the lastest version you first need to install Rtools.

Comment: Try `install.packages('spatstat.utils', type = "source")`

Comment: @KonradRudolph  thanks. It seems that I need to update my R version, which is 4.0.3 in order to install Rtools and be able to install the latest version of the package spatstat.utils